# Get around permission errors in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions, user-accounts, administrator

Apparently I'm an Administrator:

[image: Administrator]

So why am I running into this kind of dialog all the time:

[image: permission denied]

Whose permission do I need? Is there a way to `sudo` in Windows 7?

Comment: Something is not set right on your Windows PC. What are you trying to do ? Maybe there is another user account on the PC and you are trying to access his account...

Answer (score 1):

You might be transferring content to a folder on an NTFS formatted drive that you are not the owner of (this happens to me a lot while transferring stuff to external storage drives)

You need to take ownership of the folder to get around this.

Use [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/) or [take a look here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/cc753659.aspx) to do this manually.

### Taking Ownership of a folder (recursively)

1. Select the folder in Explorer and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Switch to the `Security` tab and click `Advanced`
3. Click the `Change` button
   [image: Change owner]
4. Enter your username in the `Select User or Group` dialog box that pops up and click OK
   [image: Select user or group]
5. Make sure you tick both `Replace owner...` and `Replace all child object...` checkboxes and click OK. you should now be the owner of the folder and all folders and files within that folder. 
   [image: Recursive permissions change]